# PHP's ftp_raw function with MLSD and fsockopen: weird blocking behaviour and Warning messages

Tags: php, sockets, ftp

I'm currently having a problem with FTP's `ftp_raw` function.

I need to get a very precise and verbose list of files and directories of a FTP directory (`ftp_rawlist` is not precise enough with datetimes and is not specified). So I want to use the more normalized command: `MLSD`.

I could get the list of the files I want, but after getting the data from the socket, impossible to use PHP's `ftp*` functions anymore...

Here is an extract of my code:

```
//Current folder = "/"
$directory = "/www/";

$currentFolder = ftp_pwd($ftpStream);
echo $currentFolder;
echo ' : ';
ftp_chdir($ftpStream, $directory);

$ret = ftp_raw($ftpStream, 'PASV');

if (preg_match('#^227.*\(([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\)$#', $ret[0], $matches)) {
    $controlIp = str_replace(',', '.', $matches[1]);
    $controlPort = intval($matches[2]) * 256 + intval($matches[3]);
    $socket = fsockopen($controlIp, $controlPort);
    ftp_raw($ftpStream, 'MLSD');
    $s = '';
    while (!feof($socket)) {
        $s .= fread($socket, 4096);
    }
    fclose($socket);
}

echo ftp_pwd($ftpStream); //line 256
echo ' --> ';
ftp_chdir($ftpStream, $currentFolder); //line 258

echo ftp_pwd($ftpStream); //line 260
```

Displays :

```
/ :    <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  ftp_pwd(): Transfer complete. in <b>/media/sf_web/x/webService/models/Ftp.class.php</b> on line <b>256</b><br />
--><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  ftp_chdir(): &quot;/www&quot; is current directory. in <b>/media/sf_web/x/webService/models/Ftp.class.php</b> on line <b>258</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  ftp_pwd(): CWD command successful. in <b>/media/sf_web/x/webService/models/Ftp.class.php</b> on line <b>260</b><br />
```

Errors are not consistent then.

For information, if I comment the whole "If" conditional block, I get a normal behaviour, with no warning:

```
/ : /www --> /
*/
```

Where could be my mistake? How to explain the incoherent Warning messages and the impossibility to use correctly `$ftpStream` after that?

I've been looking for a solution for hours, so your help would be very appreciated... :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP now supports `MLSD` command nativelly, since 7.2 with its [`ftp_mlsd` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mlsd.php).

---

*Original answer:*

The `MLSD`, as all FTP data transfer commands, issues multiple responses.

Typically one or more `1xx` preliminary replies, like

```
150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/path"
```

And one final response, in your case:

```
226 Transfer complete.
```

The `ftp_raw` function reads only one response, i.e. the prelimirary `150` one. Keeping the final `226` response "in queue".

Once you issue a new FTP command, i.e. the `PWD`, it finds the pending `226` response, and stops on that.

The actual `PWD` response is again left "in the queue":

```
257 /www is current directory.
```

And so on.

You get the warnings because the status codes do not match the commands. A positive response to `PWD` is `257`, not `226`. A positive response to `CWD` is `250`, not `257`, etc.

I'm afraid there's no way to get in sync as there's no PHP function to skip/read FTP reply.

So your only option is probably to disconnect and connect again.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I thought so I first added a disconnection/connection patch. But it was too dirty, so finally I gave up the idea of using PHP for FTP commands. Now using exec() with lftp. Thanks again and best regards~